# How to hide or show column in Pentaho report based on condition

Tags: reporting, pentaho

How can I show or Hide column based on condition. 
For example I have column name employees and there is parameter called $country(drop down list). I want  that employee column only show on report when country  US or Canada is chosen by user else that column does not show on report. How to add that condition on visible property of column. Is there any other steps as well to attain these results?
Thanks.

Comment: You mean interactive reporting?, report designer?

Comment: no just make column visible or not visible based on condition given in visible property.

Answer (score 0):

let's say if you are using text-field do display employee name,in style tab of text-field there is a property called visible,by default it will be true,click on plus sign of that property and you can right you condition there, like below

```
=IF([country]="US";"true";"false")
```

Comment: Actually "true" or "false" return text, so this will not work. In formula you need TRUE() or FALSE() functions to return the boolean equivalent.

Comment: @ChoCho did you tried it? it is the functionality of my project, if it doesn't work. let me know i will have a look into your report.

Comment: I've just tested it again, for some reason I did this in some instance somewhere and didn't work without using the functions, but on PRD 8 is working!, both solutions are aplicable, using functions TRUE(), FALSE() or just writing the text equivalent.